# OpenGL Camera Strafing doesnt work

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, camera, transformation

I'm currently working on a OpenGL FrameWork/Engine and as far as the OpenGL part goes, I'm quite satisfied with my results. 
On the other hand I have a serious problem getting a Camera to work. 
Moving along the Z-Axis works well, but as soon as I start to strafe (moving along the X-Axis), the whole Scene get screwed. 
You can see the result of strafing in the image below. 
The left part shows the actual scene, the right part shows the scene resulting from a strafe movement.

[image]

My code is the following.
In Constructor:

```
    //Info is a Struct with Default values
    m_projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(
    info.fieldOfView, width / height,   //info.fov = 90
    info.nearPlane, info.farPlane       // info.near = 0.1f, info.far = 1000
    );

    //m_pos = glm::vec3(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f), info.target = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)
    m_viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(m_pos, m_pos + info.target, Camera::UP);

    //combine projection and view
    m_vpMatrix = m_projectionMatrix * m_viewMatrix;
```

In the "Update"-Method I'm currently doing the following:

```
glm::mat4x4 Camera::GetVPMatrix()
{
    m_vpMatrix = glm::translate(m_vpMatrix, m_deltaPos);
    return m_vpMatrix;
}
```

As far as i know: 
The projection matrix achieves the actual perspective view. The view matrix, initially, translates and rotates the whole scene, that it is centered?
So why translating the VP-Matrix by any Z-Value works just fine, but by an X-Value doesn't?

I would like to achive a camera behaviour like this: 
Initial Cam Pos is (0,0,0) and "Center" is e.g. (0,0,-1). 
Then after Translation by X = 5: Cam Pos is (5,0,0) and Center is (5,0,-1).

Edit: Additional Question. 
Why is the Z-Coordinate affekted by VP-Transformation?

Thanks for any help! 
Best regards, Christoph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally got the solution... As you can see, I am using GLM for my matrix math. GLM stores its matrices values in column major order. Open GL wants column major ordered matrices, too. C/C++ native 2d Array layout is row major, so most of the available OpenGL/C++ tutorials state, that one should use

```
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_TRUE, &mat[0][0]);
```

With GL_TRUE meaning, that the matrix should be converted (transposed?) from row major to column major order. Because of my matrices already beeing in column major format, that makes absolutely no sense...

Changing the above to

```
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, GL_FALSE, &mat[0][0]);
```

fixed my problem...

Comment: If this solution fixed your problem, you should mark this answer as accepted (even if it's your own answer!) so that other people see that this is the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix math is not my strong point so I can't explain why your current approach doesn't work, though I have my suspicions (translating the projection matrix doesn't seem right). The following should allow you to move the camera though:

```
// update your camera position
m_pos = new_pos;
// update the view matrix
m_viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(m_pos, m_pos + info.target, Camera::UP);
// update the view-projection matrix, projection matrix never changes
m_vpMatrix = m_projectionMatrix * m_viewMatrix;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this produce a "target"-centered View? Glm lookAt should produce a matrix which focusses the target point, so no real strafe movement would be achieved. Additionally, when proceeding to rotations, the same problem would occur?

Comment: Looking at your code, your target is just an arbitrary offset of m_pos, not a fixed point in the world. This means that as the position of the camera moves so does the target. I assumed you had done this because you wanted the camera to 'look' in a fixed direction relative to the camera.

Comment: Yes, that's what i want. As the camera strafes sidewards, the focus point should do this to, the "heading" should remain unchanged.

Comment: The code should be as you wanted then. m_pos is the position of the camera in the world. The camera target should be the camera's position + a normalized direction vector. It's not obvious how you're calculating the UP vector.

Comment: UP is const glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f). I dont want roll movement, so this should be fine.

Comment: Still, the scene looks distortet when strafing

Comment: There is nothing I can see in the code you have provided and the modifications I have suggested that would cause this.